# Empty image cache for specific product in Magento 1.8?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have a custom module in Magento which automatically updates product images from an FTP directory. When a product is updated with a new image I need to manually `Flush catalog image cache` to display the new image on frontend. However, this clears all image cache and with a library of several thousand products it's not really an option.

Is it possible to clear image cache for a specific product in `PHP`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Magento (afaik) does not provide a native function for that. On *nix you can use the Shell to search through the cache folder for the (lowercase) SKU and delete those.

Please note that PHP will need the right to execute shell commands for the code below to work. After calling ::findCacheImages you can iterate through the result and delete the cached images.

Example from one of my classes:

```
/**
 * Get array of all files in the image cache tree. Provide all SKU at once for better performance.
 *
 * @param array $skus
 * @return array
 */
static public function findCacheImages(Array $skus)
{
    if (!$skus) {
        return array();
    }
    $skus     = array_unique($skus);
    $toSearch = array();
    $result   = array();
    while (count($skus) > 0) {
        $sku = array_pop($skus);
        if (trim($sku) != '') {
            $toSearch[] = $sku;
        }
        if (count($toSearch) > 50 || count($skus) == 0) {
            // Perform file search
            $bigRegex = array();
            foreach ($toSearch as $fName) {
                // Build regex
                $bigRegex[] = '.*/' . strtolower($fName) . '.*';
            }
            $bigRegexStr = implode('|', $bigRegex);
            $dir         = escapeshellcmd(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/media/catalog/product/cache/');
            $result      = array_merge(self::findFilesRegex($dir, $bigRegexStr), $result);
            $toSearch    = array();
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

/**
 * @param string $dir
 * @param string $regex
 * @return array
 */
static public function findFilesRegex($dir, $regex)
{
    $files = shell_exec("find $dir -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '$regex' -print");
    $files = explode("\n", trim($files));
    return $files;
}
```

Comment: Very usefull functions. I added them to my product update logic. Works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about default Magento cache, then you can flush the cache by using the following code at the end of the function of import images

```
 Mage::app()->cleanCache('catalog_product_'.$productId);
```

Comment: Good suggestion but unfortunately this does not flush the product image cache. I still have to go to "Cache management" and click on "Flush catalog image cache" for the image to be visible on frontend.